# I can use created TThread object for more times? (C++ Builder environment)

Tags: c++builder, tthread

Good morning,
I would like to use a `TThread` object to process numeric values.
On a recurring basis (through the `TTimer` object), different/updated values ​​are always presented in processing.

Basically:

- The first time I create and launch the `TThread` which is actually executed but not deleted.
- Subsequently (by `TTimer`), I get new values ​​for `TThread` to process.

Request:
Is there a way to "restart" the `TThread` with the new values, without creating a new `TThread` object every time? (`TThread` already exists)

This would save time, since the values ​​would always use the space allocated in the first `TThread` creation.

Comment: You could use a [`TQueue`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Contnrs.TQueue) and let the timer put stuff in that, that the thread then picks from and processes. I don't think `TQueue` is thread safe (at least, the documentation doesn't mention it) so you'll need to add that.

Comment: Good idea Ted, I'll tray it, Tk!

Comment: You can use [`TThreadList`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThreadList) ([Generic version](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TThreadList)), or [`TThreadedQueue`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TThreadedQueue).

Answer (score 1):

A `TThread` (or any other kind of thread wrapper, for that matter) cannot be "restarted" once it has finished running.  All you can do is free it.

So, to do what you are asking for, you would need to make the thread's `Execute()` method run a loop that processes your numeric values on each iteration as needed, until you are ready to signal the thread to terminate itself.

You will have to implement your own thread-safe system to push new numerics into the thread when needed, and to make the thread wait for new numerics to arrive between each loop iteration.  For instance, you could push values into a `TThreadList` or `TThreadedQueue`, signaling a waitable `TEvent` or `TMonitor` on each push, and then the thread loop can wait on that signal before pulling values on each iteration.

Otherwise, consider using `TTask` instead of `TThread`.  Tasks can utilize thread pooling internally, so you can just create a new `TTask` each time you have a new numeric to process, and let it pull out an available thread from the pool, and put the thread back in the pool when finished.